# WFE problems When building a new 2016 farm

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016

When building a new 2016 multi server farm I can get the app server to talk to SQL but the WFE will not connect to the farm. The App serve sees it but will not connect. the error I am getting is `401 UNAUTHORIZED`?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like permission issue.

- Make Sure the account which you login should have proper rights at the SQL Server. typically it is farm account or Install account which need Security Admin or DB creator rights.
- Same account also be part of local admin on SharePoint server
- Also try to pin the SQL server from the wfe server.

Comment: I have been using the network domain account (root account) to build all three servers (i.e. app server, sql server, wfe server.) I have had the three account added to all servers (i.e. SPSetup "Full control of all SP servers", SPFarm "Full control of all SP servers" & SPApp "Full control of SQL Server") But again loading/building all server with domain account. Is this not right?